# Meaning of '지' in 고래는 포유류지 어류 아닙니다

Tags: grammar

> 고래는 포우류지 어류 아닙니다 -

I've heard that here, 지 is a contrastive (like -지만), so the meaning should be 'A whale is not a fish, but a mammal.'

However, I'm more used to '지' meaning 'isn't it?'. So I might read it as 'A whale is a mammal, isn't it? It's not a fish'.

Could either of those interpretations be correct? Or can '지' not mean 'isn't it?' when it's not at the end of a sentence?

Comment: I'm not sure about the function of -지, but it is definitely different from -지만.
"고래는 포유류지만 어류 아닙니다." would mean "**Even though** a whale is a mammal, it is not a fish." (...which doesn't make much sense.) A much better example with -지만 would be "고래는 포유류지만 바다 동물입니다." (Even though a whale is a mammal, it is a marine animal.)

Comment: That -지 is defined in a dictionary: https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=78636

Answer (score 4, accepted):

고래는 포유류지 = A whale is a mammal

It came from the phrase '고래는 포유류다.'

we can rewrite the sentence to "A whale is not a mammal, and a whale is not a fish."

In this sentence '~지' means '~is ~ and'